# Retrive a field which has array of objects(ref) using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im having mongo(mongoose) collection called "asserts" and "users".
Having list of documents in "asserts" collection.
Now while adding a user I need to select multiple "asserts". So need to set "ref" to asserts collection.

Below is my modal

```
 asserts_list: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    ref: "asserts"   },
```

POST operation is working fine (i.e) I can add multiple object IDs in Mongoose in array. But while performing list using `AppComp.find({})` with populate, asserts_list is returning empty array([]).

Help me to retrieve array of object ids in find({}) using **nodejs**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define properly

```
asserts_list: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "asserts"   }],
```

and then use `populate` function

Comment: Thanks @AfifKhan, now I'm getting object ids in array of "asserts_list".But populate is not populateing those objectids to all fields.
I'm tried using .populate("asserts_list.asserts") & .populate("asserts").

Comment: Working Fine. using .populate("asserts_list").